# Algorithm for sliding puzzle does not find the optimal solution

Tags: java, algorithm

Hey I'm trying to write a solver for a n x m sliding puzzle. My algorithm finds a solution but it's not the optimal one. I took a look at BFS Algorithm since it seemed pretty fitting for this kind of problem but I have no idea on how to adapt my code accordingly. I hope someone can find the problem in my code or give my some tips on how to improve it. The performance is very poor also.

```
private static final int maxMoves = 30;
private List<Direction> solutions = new ArrayList<Direction>();

public void solveHelper(List<Direction> moves, SlidingPuzzle g){
        if(moves.size() > maxMoves){
            return;
        }
        if(g.isGameOver()){
            solutions.addAll(moves);
            return;
        }
        for(Direction dir : Direction.values()){
            Direction invDir = null;
            switch(dir){
                case UP:
                    invDir = Direction.DOWN;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    invDir = Direction.LEFT;
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    invDir = Direction.RIGHT;
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    invDir = Direction.UP;
                    break;
            }
            if(moves.size() == 0 || invDir != moves.get(moves.size() - 1)){
                if(g.moveGap(dir)){
                    solveHelper(createNewListAndCopyAndAdd(moves, dir), g);
                    g.moveGap(invDir);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Direction> createNewListAndCopyAndAdd(List<Direction> list, Direction dir){
        List<Direction> newList = new ArrayList<Direction>(list);
        newList.add(dir);
        return newList;
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe your current algorithm and why you think it should find the optimal solution?

Comment: The problem is I know that it doesn't find the optimal solution because it just gives out the solution that it finds first which isn't always (more like never) the optimal solution. It chooses 1 Direction and just goes deeper until it reaches maxMoves and then goes on to the next Direction and so on

Comment: Finding the shortest solution is an NP hard problem. Are you sure you really need the optimal solution. Is it not acceptable to produce a "good" solution?

Comment: I know but I need the optimal solution sadly. Otherwise my code would be perfectly fine :/